# ControlParameter with a GridView

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to get a value from a particular selected row of a GridView (id = "gvClient") using the syntax associated with:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvClient" etc.... />
```

The row in question is the one being edited and the data I need is in the 1st column. My question is can this be done? I am having difficulties with this and every way I try throws an error like:

> System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a property with
>   the name 'Value'

Please help.
Thank you,
J.

Comment: For gridview ControlParameter property should be SelectedValue not only Value. there are other way to fetch value from gridview  like rowcommand, OnSelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: Please give proper coding to analyse your error.